# RESTful Web Service - nested resources require many requests

Tags: rest, api-design, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have a small question regarding the REST API design for a small management software. The backend is implemented in Spring and the frontend in angular. Buildings, rooms and workplaces are managed within the software.

The interface currently has the following endpoints for this purpose:

- `/locations/buildings[/%buildingId%]`
- `/locations/building/%buildingId%/rooms`
- `/locations/rooms[/%roomId%]`
- `/locations/rooms/%roomId%/workplaces`
- `/locations/workplaces[/%workplaceId%]`

The JSON objects returned are not nested and contain HATEOAS links. Incidents that are maintained in the tool mostly relate to the workplace. That means I usually have to query the events via REST first. These contain the WorkplaceId and a link to the Workplace. Since you can't do anything big with the workplace at first, the room must then be queried via a link and finally the building.

For individual events, this still works without any problems. However, if I want to list all workplaces including room and building, for example, I have a lot of requests.

Example:

- 2 buildings
- 60 rooms each building
- 3-4 workstations per room

1. fetch buildings (1 request)
2. Get associated rooms (1 request per building = 2 in total)
3. Get workstations for each room (1 request per room = 120 in total)

The latter bothers me a lot. In order to cushion the whole thing a bit, I could pick up the whole thing once when starting the application and then always refer to this database. Unfortunately, the whole thing is ugly, since I would have to regularly check whether another user has made a change.

My next idea would be to marry the rooms and workplaces at API level and return nested objects at room level. But then the endpoint `/locations/workplaces/%workplaceId%` should still exist so that I can link incidents correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Most hypermedia formats have a feature for reducing requests by embedding them. For example, if you use the HAL format you can use `_embedded`.

Everything in this embedded structure still has a URI, and I would say it's recommended that you also make GET requests to those endpoints work just the same.

Our client ([ketting](https://github.com/badgateway/ketting)) will transparently handle `_embedded`, so if the server has things embedded it will just pre-fill a cache, but then later on it might still be needed to refresh specific endpoints without getting the whole list again, and that's when those individual GET requests can still be handy.

To avoid polling, you can always consider setting up a websocket. In a system we worked on our websocket just emitted a list of URIs that has changed, and then the client simply does `GET` requests on those URIs.